# Transparent Highlight of Selection in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

Something has changed in the way the Forge Viewer is displaying our selected objects. First when we selected a window it would stay transparent, and was only highlighted with the default or given color. Right now the windows are rendered non-transparent with the default or given color:

[image: Attachment 1]

This only happens at the first selection, the first selected object will stay non-transparent until you pan/zoom the scene or Zoom in (F) on another object:

[image: Attachment 2]

I already tried on every selection:

```
viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
```

This will reset the pre-selected object to his original transparent material, but the selected object will be highlighted un-transparent every time.

I do not use a custom selection here, this is just default behaviour. Any advice?

Comment: What version of the Viewer do you have targeted in your setup?

Comment: @JaimeRosales I targeted the latest version v4.0.1.

Comment: And have this worked in the past, with version 3.3 so I can let our engineers know about the recent change so they can take a look at it. But I first need confirmation.

Comment: @JaimeRosales Yes it did work with with 3.3, if I target 3.3.5 it does work again.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in the Viewer version 6.4 Currently we are at version 7 let me know if the problem persists but should be good to go now.