# Transparant highlight of selection in Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

A time ago we created the following issue/question:
[Transparent Highlight of Selection in Forge Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49048832/transparent-highlight-of-selection-in-forge-viewer?noredirect=1#comment85229026_49048832)

We now upgraded to version 6 and are still experiencing this problem.
Is this a known issue or something that gets investigated at the moment?

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this problem, this is not yet fixed. Our tracking code is `LMV-3722`

**Update**

This fix was released on version `6.4`

Comment: Hi,
Is there progress for this issue?

Comment: Sorry, not yet :-(